# Compiling C++ with C codes on VS Code using G++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, linker, g++

My Case is as follows:
I made a GUI program (wxWidgets based) on Microsoft Visual Studio where this code was running fine mixing both C++ and C files, basically the C files do very little things but I can't discard them cause I am very beginner with C++ OOP - I have OOP background from Java which I feel far different than C++ - but I can deal with it to certain extent. Anyway, the program was running fine on Visual Studio 2019 but when I place it on another computer with no Visual Studio installation, it start firing  missing `.dll`s after little research I found this is due to the lack of Visual Studio installation on that computer and I don't have admin rights to install these `.dll` files. I looked for rebuilding the files on VS Code, I used the g++ compiler so I needed to configure wxWidgets with MinGw compiler. I managed to make the Hello World code on wxWidgets work. When I ran my code it didn't work after a little bit of struggle I eliminated any errors, however when I built the code for Debug/Release this what it get on the terminal:

> C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUB3ReN.o: In function
> `ZN5cMainC2Ev`: C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:13:
> undefined reference to `Bus_Construct`
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:13: undefined reference
> to `Decker_Construct` C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUB3ReN.o:
> In function `ZN5cMain16CalculateClickedER14wxCommandEvent`:
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:426: undefined reference
> to `getCG` C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:442: undefined
> reference to `getCGz`
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:454: undefined reference
> to `getPassCGX` C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:455:
> undefined reference to `getPassCGY`
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:456: undefined reference
> to `getPassCGZ` C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:457:
> undefined reference to `totalCG`
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:470: undefined reference
> to `delay` C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:528: undefined
> reference to `freeSeats`
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:530: undefined reference
> to `freeSingleDecker` C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUB3ReN.o:
> In function `ZN5cMain19GenerateGroupsClickER14wxCommandEvent`:
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:622: undefined reference
> to `initSingleDecker`
> C:/Users//Desktop/wxTest/src/cMain.cpp:627: undefined reference
> to `initSeats` collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status The
> terminal process
> "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command
> C:<USER>\Softwares\MinGW\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -g
> C:\Users<USER>\Desktop\wxTest\src**.cpp
> C:\Users<USER>\Desktop\wxTest\src**.c -o
> C:\Users<USER>\Desktop\wxTest\build\debug\cApp.exe -I
> C:\Users<USER>\Desktop\wxTest\include -I
> C:\wx\wxWidgets-3.1.5\include -I
> C:\wx\wxWidgets-3.1.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -L
> C:\wx\wxWidgets-3.1.5\lib\gcc_dll -l wxmsw31ud_core -l wxbase31ud"
> terminated with exit code: 1

What I noticed is some mangled name with `ZN5cMainC2Ev` which originally a class name cMain.
I think the trick is at the `task.json` arguments:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Debug",
        "command": "C:\\Amir\\Softwares\\MinGW\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\debug\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\include",
            "-I",
            "C:\\wx\\wxWidgets-3.1.5\\include",
            "-I",
            "C:\\wx\\wxWidgets-3.1.5\\lib\\gcc_dll\\mswud",
            "-L",
            "C:\\wx\\wxWidgets-3.1.5\\lib\\gcc_dll",
            "-l",
            "wxmsw31ud_core",
            "-l",
            "wxbase31ud",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\Amir\\Softwares\\MinGW\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe"
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Release",
        "command": "C:\\Amir\\Softwares\\MinGW\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\BusCalcs.c",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\CG_Engine.c",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\Helper.c",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\release\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-I",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\include",
            "-I",
            "C:\\wx\\wxWidgets-3.1.5\\include",
            "-I",
            "C:\\wx\\wxWidgets-3.1.5\\lib\\gcc_dll\\mswu",
            "-L",
            "C:\\wx\\wxWidgets-3.1.5\\lib\\gcc_dll",
            "-l",
            "wxmsw31u_core",
            "-l",
            "wxbase31u",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\Amir\\Softwares\\MinGW\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Did you use [`extern "C"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/10077) on the C++ declarations of the C bits?

Comment: "the C files do very little things but I can't discard them cause I am very beginner with C++ OOP" -- Do you understand that you don't *have* to use OOP in C++?

Comment: Do not compile C source files with a C++ compiler (such as g++), which you appear to have configured your project to do. At least in Release mode. In Debug mode, you seem to be compiling a smaller set of files. Compile C with a C compiler (gcc) and C++ with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @FredLarson yes the .h C files are inside an extern "C" scope/block

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am totally new to "make" files or in other words these compilers and linkers configuration files/scripts. So what to write in the task.json to compile these C files with the gcc compiler away from the g++ and would they be all linked together into 1 .exe file? by the way I want all cpp and c files are all compiled and linked together at the end of the day for both Debug and Release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by renaming the `.C` files to `.CPP` files it build correctly for both Debug and Release and my App was working correctly however when I ran it on another computer I got loads of missing `.dll`s more than I used to get from VS2019 build I think my problem is now handling how to optimize my installation of the application on any computer.

Thanks All.